# SQL alwayson manual Failover Cluster failed because a duplicate IP address detected

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

When I manually tried to make a failover I got the following errors: "SQL always on Cluster IP address resource listener cannot be brought online because a duplicate IP address was detected on the network. Please ensure all IP addresses are unique. event 1049"

As a result, all the resources of the Cluster\Listener\witness were in a failure state and could not be moved back to online state.

When I aborted the failover attempts Everything returned to normal.

version: SQL SERVER 2016 SP2 Enterprise edition 2 nodes (Primary and secondary)

appreciated to receive your response and suggestions

Thanks and Regards

Erez Hasman

Comment: I highly suspect the service account managing your SQL Server Services doesn't have sufficient Domain Privileges to migrate the IP between your failover nodes.  Take a look at this article for the necessary permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/prestage-cluster-adds

Comment: How did you attempt this failover - from failover cluster manager or from SQL Server using `ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG] FAILOVER`?

Comment: This could be due to any number of things and it would most likely require troubleshooting at the time the issue occurs.  You might want to check your routers to ensure that gratuitous ARP is enabled, as that is used when an IP address is taken offline or brought online

Comment: Are the primary and secondary on the same subnet?  I.e., was the secondary trying to bring the same IP address online that was online on the primary?  One thing that can happen on a node in a different subnet is that someone thinks the IP address is available since it's almost always offline, so they use it for a different system.

Comment: @Tony I'm working with author and he failed to answer here:
1. the service account is admin in the domain, we verified it 
2. the failover was attempted through UI
3. same subnet

Comment: @HandyD it was done through UI

Comment: I don't think there's anything anyone here can do to help.  The first step in troubleshooting would be to confirm whether the other system still had the IP address bound to the network adapter.  If it did, then it's either a defect or some odd configuration problem.  I don't know how you could configure it wrongly to run into this problem.